# Save OpenGL scene to a TBitmap - glReadPixels returning empty data?

Tags: delphi, opengl

I'm attempting to save an OpenGL created scene as a TBitmap.  The problem I'm having is glReadPixels is returning all empty data (all 0's).  Thoughts on why this would occur?  I'm attempting to capture the currentl OpenGL context.  (display on screen is all working fine).  This is with Delphi 7 under Windows.

```
var
   pbuf: pointer;
   y: integer;
   bmp: TBitmap;
   p1, p2: pointer;
begin
   GetMem( pbuf, pnScene.Width * pnScene.Height * 4);
   glReadPixels( 0, 0, pnScene.Width, pnScene.Height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pbuf);
   //<------  pbuf now contains all 0's  ---------->

   bmp := TBitmap.Create;
   bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
   bmp.Width := pnScene.Width;
   bmp.Height := pnScene.height;

   for y := 0 to (pnScene.Height -1) do
   begin
      p1 := bmp.ScanLine[y];
      p2 := pointer( integer(pbuf)+ (y * bmp.Width * 4));
      CopyMemory( p1, p2, bmp.Width * 4);
   end;

   bmp.SaveToFile( 'c:\test\temp.bmp');
   bmp.Free;
   FreeMem( pbuf);
end;
```

And suggestions/thoughts are greatly welcome!

**Addendum:**

Ultimately the plan was to place the glReadPixels() call right after the rendering calls for purposes of recording video.  When I did that, it worked ok, so this ended up being something of a non-problem.

Comment: Did you check for errors? glGetError

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have mentioned - no errors from the glReadPixels()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are doing this from the same thread as where you created the GL context. If this is a callback function you supply to a third-party library then it may execute in another thread without you even realizing it. This happened to me once and all I got was zeroes just like you.

Comment: This wasnt the problem, but it did lead me to try embedding the glReadPixels() into the location exactly where ultimately it would be anyways (my code above was just a testing function) - and that worked.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to retrieve a picture that has been already swapped to the front buffer of a double buffered window. Then try prepending a `glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT)` before `glReadPixels(...)`

Comment: I had actually tried that, but it didnt seem to make a difference.  Though I can see how that'd be something that probably should be in there anyways just in case subsequent code changes that setting.

Answer (score 0):

In the `for` loop you must change the statement:

```
p1 := bmp.ScanLine[y];
```

to

```
p1 := bmp.ScanLine[OpenGlPanel.Height -1 -y];
```

Otherwise, the copied bitmap will be upside-down.